# Query elemMatch Date

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5359816b036493327d7cae95"),
"_class" : "com.myproject.MyObjectDTO",
"signals" : [ 
    {
        "signalType" : "ABC",
        "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
        "date" : ISODate("2001-12-13T23:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "signalType" : "ABD",
        "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
        "date" : ISODate("2001-12-16T23:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "signalType" : "ABF",
        "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
        "date" : ISODate("2001-12-17T23:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "signalType" : "ABG",
        "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
        "date" : ISODate("2001-12-18T23:00:00.000Z")
    },
    ...
}
```

with around 160 000 entries and 3000 signals per entry.

I tried to find documents with a date greater than an specified date (I'm using `$date` because I query through Spring Data):

```
db.analysisDTO.find(
      "signals" : {
         "$elemMatch" : { 
            "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2001-12-01T22:00:00.000Z"}})
```

The request takes more than 7 minutes and I get no result. Even if I change `$gte` to `$lte`, I don't get anything.

Is the request wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$date` operator is a part of the [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) spec and that's what you get as default with `mongoexport` but you don't want to use it in the query criteria.

Try using the `ISODate()` constructor instead:

```
db.analysisDTO.find({"signals" : {
        "$elemMatch" : { 
           "date" : { 
             "$gte" : new ISODate("2001-12-01T22:00:00.000Z")}}}});
```

The reason for the 7 minute length is likely because the entire data set is being scanned into memory to check all fields.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it worked with "new ISODate" and not with "new Date"... don't know why...

Comment: OK, cool - updated to use the ISODate constructor to avoid confusion for others :)